# Transformar nome dos campos postados em variáveis de PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho um formulário com campos dinâmicos.
com inputs com names assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nome_prod1" value="Shampoo Hidratante Dazen Elegance">
<input data-theme="b" value="0" name="qtd1" type="text" id="1"/>

<input type="hidden" name="nome_prod2" value="Shampoo Hidratante Dazen Elegance">
<input data-theme="b" value="0" name="qtd2" type="text" id="1"/>
```

cada um com seu value, o problema é na hora de mostrar isso pois não queria mostrar tão pouco salvar no banco os campos que tem quantidade `0`.

Usei o comando:

```
foreach( $_POST as $nome_campo => $valor)
{ 
   $comando = "$" . $nome_campo . "='" . $valor . "';"; 
   eval($comando); 
}
```

Porem ele trouxe todos os inputs, tentei tratar pra não mostrar os que tem `qtd = 0`
mas o problema está em buscar a variável eu coloquei um contador `$i` dentro `foreach`, então o nome da variável `qtd` eu tentei chamar assim:

```
if ($qtd{$i} == 0 ) {}
```

Mas não funcionou, como eu faço isso buscar uma variável dinâmica?

```
$qtd1
$qtd2
$qtd3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, respondendo ao que foi perguntado, um caminho seria usar "variáveis variáveis":

```
foreach( $_POST as $nome_campo => $valor) { 
   $$nome_campo = $valor;
}
```

Mas isso está longe de ser uma boa idéia. Qualquer mau uso do seu PHP (por exemplo, o cliente enviando dados arbitrários) vai sobreescrever variáveis da aplicação.

Como bem lembrado pelo Papa Charlie, o PHP até tem algo pronto que já faz isso automaticamente, o [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php).

Como as soluções acima (seja o `extract` ou o *loop*) tem seus problemas inerentes, uma solução mais elegante seria usar esta estrutura:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nome_prod[]" value="Shampoo Hidratante Dazen Elegance">
<input data-theme="b" value="0" name="qtd[]" type="text" id="1"/>
```

E no PHP algo assim:

```
$nome  = $_POST['nome_prod'];
$qtd   = $_POST['qtd'];

// aqui é só usar os dados como quiser, já estão indexados desde a captura.
$count = count( $qtd );
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i ) {
   echo 'Produto: '.$nome[$i].' - Quantidade: '.$qtd[$i]."<br>\n";
}
```

Numa aplicação completa, é necessário sanitizar os dados antes do uso, obviamente (independente do *approach* usado).

Quanto a não usar valores zerados, basta algo assim dentro do *loop*:

```
if( 0 + $qtd[$i] ) {
    // usa o valor como quiser
}
```

o código dentro do bloco do `if` só será executado com valores diferentes de 0. O artifício usado é forçar um *cast* com `0 +` para tratar o valor como numérico (tem várias maneiras de se fazer isto, essa é uma delas. veja como fazer os casts e conversões no manual do PHP, na parte de variáveis).

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a questão, mas não seria o caso de usar `extract`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie seria se fosse para incentivar a primeira idéia dele, que eu condeno. É que no extract não dá pra ele por um IF como eu mencionei acima, ou pega tudo ou não pega nada. eval, extract, $_REQUEST, $$variables e tudo que é muito "genérico" no PHP acaba sendo um problemão. Mas se você postar um exemplo com extract, acho que é uma alternativa válida (que eu não recomendo, mas não estaria errada a resposta). Só sugiro deixar claro que sofre dos mesmos problemas que eu mencionei acima. De qq forma, é um comentário válido.

Comment: Eu sei, concordo 1000%, e nem me atreveria a responder usando `extract`. O ideal seria recomendar uma abordagem mais correta como você fez. Eu é que não tinha entendido bem a questão, queria saber se o que precisava era na mesma linha do `extract`.

Comment: @PapaCharlie neste caso, pus uma menção ao seu comentário na resposta, ao menos não fica faltando avisar da opção.